# Lotus Notes custom view received mail

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I am using lotus notes 8.5.2 on windows 7. I would like to create a custom view that shows all emails EXCEPT sent mail. In other words it contains: INBOX & ALL FOLDERS.

Currently my ALL DOCUMENTS view has the following formula conditions: `SELECT @IsNotMember("A"; ExcludeFromView) & IsMailStationery != 1 & Form != "Group" & Form != "Person"`

The SENT view has the conditions: `SELECT DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView))`

My thinking is that I should be able to exclude the SENT conditions from the ALL DOCUMENT condition ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking all the documents that aren't in the Sent view isn't quite right, because there are a few documents that aren't in the Sent view that are also excluded from the All Documents view.  The logic you want is:

```
SELECT (in the All Documents view) AND NOT (in the Sent view)
```

So, first make a copy of All Documents.  You're going to keep the selection formula from the All Documents view, and put & !( ) after it, like this:

```
SELECT ( @IsNotMember("A"; ExcludeFromView) & IsMailStationery != 1 & Form != "Group" & Form != "Person" ) & !( )
```

Now, just copy the selection formula from the Sent view and put it between those empty parens, so the result is this:

```
SELECT ( @IsNotMember("A"; ExcludeFromView) & IsMailStationery != 1 & Form != "Group" & Form != "Person" ) & !( DeliveredDate = "" & PostedDate != "" & !(@IsMember("S"; ExcludeFromView)) )
```